# What is the meaning of "Molto's nose sticking out of Nico's bellybutton"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Raymond Horgan got a murder case and telling this words to Rozat:

> Raymond Horgan: I can hear Della Guardia now. "lf Raymond Horgan can't
>   protect his own attorneys, how can he protect citizens?" Tommy Molto's
>   secretary said he wasn't coming in today. Some fucking Acting Head of
>   Homicide he turned out to be, the little creep. I should have fired
>   him when we fired Nico. If I had balls, I'd do it now. I want you to
>   handle this  case personally.
>
> Rozart: I will assign it to somebody.
>
> Raymond Horgan: Who will you assign it to? Homicide? Tommy Molto? For
>   Christ's sake! Della Guardia would love that. Molto would tip him off
>   on everything. They're so close you can see **Molto's nose sticking out
>   of Nico's bellybutton.**

Comment: It means "Molto has his head up Nico's ass", as Horgan might put it.

Answer (score 1):

The ability to see Molto's nose sticking out of Nico's belly button is an exaggerated way of saying **Molto has his head up Nico's ass**.

To clarify, this does not mean that Molto has literally inserted his head into Nico's anus, but rather intends to **figuratively** refer to one of the following observations:

**A)** Molto is kowtowing to Nico in order to gain a particular advantage.

**B)** Molto and Nico are very close friends. To the extent that Molto would be willing to do practically anything for his friend Nico.

Given that the author mentions that the two are close, it appears that **Choice B** is a better description of the phrase's meaning.